# Question about trailing return type in C++17

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction, function-templates

I have the following piece of code which compiles fine:

```cpp
template <typename T> 
struct A {T t;};

template <typename T> // 1 
A(T) -> A<T>;  // function template declaration with trailing return type compiles fine.
```

But the following variations of the same function declaration do not compile:

```cpp
template <typename T>  // 2
auto A(T) -> A<T>; // error: redefinition of 'A' as different kind of symbol

template <typename T>  // 3
A<T> A(T); // error: redefinition of 'A' as different kind of symbol
```

please help me in understanding the rationale behind why those didn't compile

Comment: When asking questions like this, always provide the text of the compilation error.

Comment: @NeilButterworth added actual compilation error message. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> // function template declaration with trailing return type compiles fine.

```
template <typename T> // 1 
A(T) -> A<T>;  // function template declaration with trailing return type compiles fine.
```

Not exactly.

For a function declaration with explicit trailing return type, you have to add `auto` before the name of the function.

Your "1" code example it's a new C++17 user defined deduction guide (see [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) for more information).

Given your template `A` class, you're saying the compiler that when you define a variable as follows

```
A  a{42l};
```

you're defining a `A<long>` variable, because the type of the template parameter is deduced from the argument of the constructor (`42l`).

About following codes

```
template <typename T>  // 2
auto A(T) -> A(T); // error: use of class template 'A' requires template  arguments
```

Now you're using correctly `auto` before the name, so you're declaring a function; unfortunately the name can't be `A` (it's the name of a struct) and the return type can't be `A(T)` (maybe `A<T>`)

```
template <typename T>  // 3
A<T> A(T); // error: redefinition of 'A' as different kind of symbol
```

Now you're correctly declaring a template function returning an `A<T>` but remain the other problem: the name can't be `A` (it's the name of a struct)

Comment: Yeah, It was a typo in //2 for the return type. I corrected it as A<T> now. Thanks.